# Setting protobuf properties by name

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

To avoid too much spaghetti style code, I'd like to set certain properties of a *golang* protobuf object by name. So lets say there's some kind of `.proto` definition like

```
syntax = "proto3";
package foo;

message User {
    uint64 uid = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

and code accessing it like

```
o := foo.User{Name: "John Doe"}
o.Uid = 40
```

exists. I'd like to be able to set `Uid` without the dotted notation. Reflection constructs like

```
r := reflect.ValueOf(o)
f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName("Uid")
f.SetUint(42)
```

seem to fail, because `Uid` is not *addressable*. I found several posts about struct fields *not being addressable*, but it's still unclear (to me as a "golang newbie") what has to be done in this context to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to `o` to `reflect.ValueOf`. By simply passing the value, the fields of the struct will not be addressable.

```
r := reflect.ValueOf(&o)
f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName("Uid")
f.SetUint(42)
```

If at all possible, however, I would try to implement this without reflection. Either use a map in your protocol buffer definition, or a switch in your Go code:

```
switch name {
case "Uid":
    o.Uid = uintValue
case "Name"
    o.Name = stringValue
}
```

The non-reflect code is less likely to fail at runtime.

Comment: Doh. That works. And just because of one little missing ampersand ;-) Thanks for your quick response!